# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular

When I try to bind data, I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.

This is my code:

```
 <div *ngFor="let edu of employee.education_qualification">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="education_detail">Education Detail</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      [(ngModel)]="edu.education_detail" [ngModelOptions]="
      {standalone: 
      true}">
    </div>
 </div>
```

[image: pic of database]

Comment: You are trying to iterate something else than an array, looks like an object of objects to me...

Comment: please check the attached pic @AJT_82

Comment: Are you sure that your employee.education_qualification exist and is Array? Try to see it with {{ employee.education_qualification | json}}

Comment: Based on the error message you are clearly trying to iterate something else than an array. I then assume `education_qualification` is an object. Hard to say with that pic. But it's definitely not an array because of that error message.

Comment: In employee.education_qualification I got the object                              Object {-Kr0fsZO0-K2slWY9-bR: Object, -Kr1-n-U7GLS2snd448I: Object}

Comment: Well that means, like suspected, `education_qualification` is an object, which is not iterable with `*ngFor`. You need to either convert it to an array, or maybe use a custom pipe.

Comment: how to convert it in array ?

Comment: In object if I use Object {0: Object,1: Object}  then its allow to bind

Comment: @KrunalJoshi you can't bind an object how it allows to bind?

Comment: I can not bind this :Object {-Kr0fsZO0-K2slWY9-bR: Object, -Kr1-n-U7GLS2snd448I: Object}  but I can bind  this Object {0: Object,1: Object}

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent{
employee: []

get(){
this.employee= yourCollection //data you are receiving 
  }
}
```

now use it in you html as

```
<div *ngFor="let edu of employee">
{{edu.education_qualification}}
```

Comment: same error @k11k2

Comment: @KrunalJoshi marked as duplicate, you can find there.